# One port resonator critical coupling Q factor measurement using S11

Tags: resonance

I saw this youtube video which says there are two methods measuring unloaded Q factor.
He says there are two options as shown bellow.
I have a one port resonator.
I could not find anywhere the theory of 2.5 dB he says in the video.
Is there some book that shows that?
Thanks.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DgmH9XsfLA&t=1s
[image]

Comment: Please start each sentence with capital letter.

Comment: Beats me. What's being calculated? Why the arbitrary cutoff (2.5dB)? What is the circuit, how is it wired, what are we measuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is simply doing what he says, applying the approach in Matthaei, Young and Jones, "Microwave Filters, Impedance-Matching Networks, and Coupling Structures", section 11.02 on how to measure the Q of a resonator.  He has digitized Fig 11.02-3, with an approximation that is valid for these two ranges:

[image]